# select distinct of a column and order by date column but without showing the date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following simple query will return result with name and date which is order by date.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Name, Date
FROM    dbo.Table WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY DATE
```

**Result**

```
 Name  |     Date  
 --------------------
   a   |  31-Jul-2013  
   a   |  31-Aug-2013  
   a   |  30-Sep-2013  
   b   |  31-Oct-2013  
   b   |  30-Nov-2013  
   a   |  31-Dec-2013
```

How can i select distinct only the Name but the sequence of the Name must be order by date?

**New result**

```
 Name  
  a  
  b  
  a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
WITH Names AS (
   SELECT
      Name,
      Seq = Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY SomeDate)
         - Dense_Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY SomeDate)
   FROM
      dbo.Names
)
SELECT Name
FROM Names
GROUP BY Name, Seq
ORDER BY Min(Seq)
;
```

**[Run this live in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9f37/1)**

This will return the A, B, A pattern you requested.

You can't use a simple DISTINCT because you're asking to display a single value, but order by **all** the dates that the value may have associated with it. What if your data looks like this?

```
Name  Date
----  ----
A     2014-01-01
B     2014-02-01
B     2014-03-01
A     2014-04-01
```

How do you decide whether to put A first, or B first, based one some theoretical ordering by the date?

That is why I had to do the above subtraction of windowing functions, which should order things how you want.

**Notes**

I call this technique a "simulated PREORDER BY". `Dense_Rank` does not offer any way to preorder the rows before ranking based on ordering. If you could do `Dense_Rank() OVER (PREORDER BY Date ORDER BY Name)` to indicate that you want to order by `Date` first, but don't want it to be part of the resulting rank calculation, you'd be set! However, that doesn't exist. After some study a while back I hit on the idea to use a combination of windowing functions to accomplish the purpose, and the above query represents that result.

Note that you *must* also `GROUP BY` the `Name`, not just the resulting subtracted windowing expressions, in order for everything to work correctly, because the expression, while unique to the other column (in this case, `Name`), can result in duplicate values across the entire set (two different value Names can have the same expression result). You can assign a new rank or other windowing function if there is a desire for a value that can be ordered by individually.

Answer (score 0):

I think a common table expression (CTE) will work here:

```
with cte as(
SELECT  DISTINCT Name, Date
FROM    dbo.Table WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY DATE
)
select Name 
from cte 
order by Date
```

Comment: error. **The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.**

Comment: yes! sorry about that. I'll leave this up for educational purposes.